# Force PDF Download in ASP.NEt with IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox, pdf, google-chrome

So, I user a bit of code to force a download on my ASP.Net based project. This bit of code works in Firefox and Chrome, bu not in IE for some strange reason. Even stranger, it worked in all three initially, and just stopped working in IE recently. Below is the code I used, please let me know if any adjustments need to be made or what the problem with with may be.

```
 string path = MapPath(fname);
    string name = Path.GetFileName(path);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(path);
    string type = "Application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=" + path);
    Response.WriteFile(path);
    Response.End();
```

More details
Here is the revamped code, still doesnt work for IE.

```
 string path = MapPath(fname);
    string name = Path.GetFileName(path);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(path);
    string type = "Application/pdf";
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ContentType = type;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=" + path);
    Response.WriteFile(path);
    Response.End();
```

Comment: You should use [System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.contentdisposition.aspx) to construct the header if you're using user-supplied filenames - that'll cope with spaces in filenames and non-ASCII characters correctly. Or if this is MVC then you can just use `return File(...);`.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably try to set the mime type to "application/octet-stream". If you don't want a specific handler to respond to the mime-type.

Comment: Exactly what I do in such a case, too.

Comment: I used them both and they yield the same results

Answer (score 1):

Should this code

```
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=" + path);
```

be changed as

```
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=" + name + "." + ext);
```

or

```
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=" + name + ".pdf");
```

Other things to check for

1. Response.Buffer to true in the beginning
2. Response.clear in the beginning
3. Use response.binarywrite instead of writefile
4. Response flush at the end
5. Ensure no HTML or space characters written to the response.stream other than the binarywrite.

Comment: I still think you should use the ContentDispositon class so the name is escaped correctly. But why BinaryWrite not WriteFile? It doesn't look like he has the file in memory.

Comment: Why would it be slower? I'd expect it'd be at least as fast as loading into memory and BinaryWriting it out yourself. But maybe he wants [TransmitFile](http://forums.asp.net/t/1275581.aspx) instead.

Comment: A pdf file contains both binary and text content. All of it needs to be binary written. With writefile, the browser's error correction code will try grab the file as text and then find binary flowing in. With Binarywrite, there is no confusion particularly with brain-dead browsers like IE. There are some tests done with both methods and binarywrite is found to be faster. But as you say, transmitfile is the better option.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following two lines at the top, fixed it for me:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
```

Comment: string path = MapPath(fname);
        string name = Path.GetFileName(path);
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(path);
        string type = "Application/pdf";
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = type;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=" + path);
        Response.WriteFile(path);
        Response.End();

Comment: @Craig - are you saying it works for you w/ the those two lines?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The reason it was not going through was due to an extra form that was present on the master page, apparently overlaying the buttons. Once that was fixed, It worked properly in all browsers.